# Linux shell script "read" command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, sh

So, I'm new to scripting, and I'm having some problems. The command I need to execute is:

```
read -p Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid "device1" ; 
read -p Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid "device2" ; 
read -p Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid "device3"
```

That command works, but when I set it as a variable ie:

```
com="read -p Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid "device1" ; 
read -p Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid "device2" ; 
read -p Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid "device3""
```

and execute it as: $com it does not work. Probably because the read command is trying to set my input to the variables device1 and ; .
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Execute as `bash -c "$com"`

Comment: Why are you trying to mix data and code?

Comment: Perhaps you need to read the manual section on [Shell functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) or this [friendlier tutorial](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions)

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 3):

You're running into problems with the order in which things are expanded by the shell.

A simpler example:

```
$ command='echo one ; echo two'
$ $command
one ; echo two
```

The semicolon in the value of `$command` is taken as part of the argument to `echo`, not as a delimiter between two `echo` commands.

There might be a way to resolve this so it works the way you want, but why bother? Just define a shell function. Using my simple example:

```
$ command() { echo one ; echo two ; }
$ command
one
two
$
```

Or using yours:

```
com() {
    read -p "Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid: " device1
    read -p "Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid: " device2
    read -p "Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid: " device3
}
```

Note that I've added ": " at the end of the prompts. I've also removed the unnecessary semicolons and the quotation marks around the variable names (since the argument has to be a valid variable name, it doesn't need to be quoted).

Answer (score 0):

You are not completing the quotes.

```
 com="read -p Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid "device1"
```

Quotes always look for a pair and you are missing that.

```
> com="read -p Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid:  device1"
> $com
Enter_the_DEVICE_Bssid:abc123
> echo $device1
abc123
```

Here I am using bash shell.